# PhoneGap Upload images to Server by restfull WS (Server side processing off data)

Tags: c#, javascript, android, cordova, wcf-rest

I am trying to upload image from my PhoneGap application to some folder on server. I have restful WS on my server side with following method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  UriTemplate = "fileUpload")]
    string fileUpload(Stream fileStream); 


public string fileUpload(Stream fileStream)
         {
         try
             {
             FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("D:\\FileUpload\\" + "images.jpg", FileMode.Create);

             byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
             int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
             do
                 {
                 bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
                 totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                 } while (bytesRead > 0);

             fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
             fileToupload.Close();
             fileToupload.Dispose();

             return "Success;

             }
         catch (Exception e)
             {
             return e.Message;
             throw (e);
             }                   
         }
```

I used the most common example from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions  and it is uploads images on the right place and gives me success call, but I cannot open image after it, "windows viewer" says "damaged, corrupted or is to large". 
When I open image in notepad++ i have following text on the begging off image:

```
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1";

test
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value2";

param
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="32"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

When I delete these part, I get original correct image.
How to proceed these data on my server side. I wanna pull out image name and parameters and use it as a string, and push only image content to my image without these parameters?

Thanks,
Milos